# c++11 std::mutex compiler error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

This a quest about deadlock in C++11 standard.

In the sec3.2.4 of C++ Concurrency in Action, there is an example for
preventing multithreads from deadlock. For guys without this book, in 
addition, there is an another almost similar example you can refer to:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag

The problem I encountered is that the codes of both codes arise compiler-errors 
in Visual Studio 2012. The error message is:

```
'std::mutex::mutex': cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex'
```

This problem also happens in the following simpler code than in cppreference.com:

```
struct bank_account {
    std::mutex m;
};
void transfer(bank_account &from, bank_account &to)
{
    std::lock(from.m, to.m);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bank_account my_account;
    bank_account your_account;

    std::thread t1(transfer, my_account, your_account);  // compiler-error!

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Should it mean a rare example of wrong sample code on Cppreference.com?

Comment: @SChepurin You're right, the example had an error. I just fixed it.

Comment: The another wrong thing in this sample code is std::lock_guard declaration without template instantiation, i.e. std::lock_guard<std::mutex>.

Comment: @juanchopanza - That was fast and, i guess, correct fix ).

Comment: @cbel good catch. Fixed that one too. I guess whoever posted the original didn't test it.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Now it works - http://liveworkspace.org/code/2pBC6p$2. I've  also noticed, that some Cppreference.com samples having no "Output" field are (may be) not tested due to compiler's no compliant to latest standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mutexes` are not copyable or assignable, and the `std::thread` constructor is attempting to make a copy. You can circumvent this by using an `std::reference_wrapper` via `std::ref`:

```
std::thread t1(transfer, std::ref(my_account), std::ref(your_account));
```

alternatively, you can pass temporary `bank_accounts`:

```
std::thread t1(transfer, bank_account(), bank_account());
```

This will most likely result in the `bank_accounts` being "moved" rather than copied, although it is also possible that the copy will be avoided via *copy elision*.

Comment: I got it, it works! Many thanks, also thank to Joachim and billz!

Comment: What would be the use of transfering money between "temporary bank accounts"? :-) I bet an account isn't copyable either, or everyone would be rich.

Comment: @BoPersson these days, all banks are temporary, so I assume so are the accounts contained therein :-) I also hear that lots of money can be made transferring between temporary accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You are making copy of `my_account` and `your_account` to [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), but std::mutex is neither copyable nor movable.

Try pass by reference:

```
 std::thread t1(transfer, std::ref(my_account), std::ref(your_account));
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

> The mutex class is non-copyable.

A mutex can't be copied or moved.